# My updated data-slide using javascript is not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am updating my data-slide value using javaScript it's updating also but not effecting the slider.

```js
var firstName = document.getElementById('firstName');
var lastName = document.getElementById('lastName');
var dataSlide = document.getElementById('dataSlide');
   
function information_count(){
    if (firstName.value == '' || lastName.value == '') {
        dataSlide.setAttribute('data-slide', 'none');
    } else {
        dataSlide.setAttribute('data-slide', 'next');
    }
}
```

```html
<h5 class="level">First Name</h5>
<input type="text" placeholder="First Name" class="contact_input rounded" name="first_name" id="firstName">

<h5 class="level">Last Name</h5>
<input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" class="contact_input rounded" id="lastName">

<a href="#carouselControl" role="button" id="dataSlide">
  <button class="btn btn-lg btn-dark float-left" onclick="information_count()">
     <i class="fas fa-chevron-circle-right"></i>
  </button>
</a>
```

Comment: delete `</h1>` .

Comment: I think your javascript needs to be inside a function called information_count()? It currently is just floating there.

Comment: I did that already before but forgot to show here but thanks i have edited my question.

Comment: Since the provided code does work, that means your slider isn't being refreshed or updated to check that value. Which slider are you using?

Comment: I'm using a bootstrap carousel my input fields slide but my button is fixed on a same position only the input field slide in order to get multiple inputs.